# How to insert a line at a particular offset in a file using Python

Tags: python

```py
file_name = '/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/HWDataList.txt'  
for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name, inplace=1):  
    if 'nail' in line:  
        line = line.rstrip()  
        line = line.replace(line, line+'\n'+'hammer'+'\n')  
    print(line)
```

The text file looks like this:

```
xxxx  
yyyy  
zzzzz  
nail  
kkkk  
jjjjj
```

When it is done I want to see it like this:

```
xxxx  
yyyy  
zzzzz  
nail  
hammer  
kkkk  
jjjjj
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the aid of additional modules you could do this:

```
FILENAME='/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt'

with open(FILENAME, 'r+') as foo:
    all_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in foo.readlines()]
    try:
        i = all_lines.index('nail')
        all_lines.insert(i+1, 'hammer')
        foo.seek(0)
        foo.writelines(line+'\n' for line in all_lines)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code might help you out.

```
import fileinput

file_name = 'Your File Path'

for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name, inplace=1):
    if 'nail' in line:
        line = line.rstrip() + '\n' + 'hammer' + '\n'
    print(line, end='')
```

Comment: WOWOWO it works. I struggled for hours on this. The (file_name, inplace=1) that box is highlighted by the editor and the warning says: FileInput cannot be (str, int) it has to be Union. All the while I thought that was my bug. Any fix to remove that warning please? THANKS a lot

Comment: Just replace inplace =1 to inplace =True .

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I rearranged your code for visual comfort

```py
import fileinput

file_name = '/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/HWDataList.txt'

for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name, inplace=True):
    if 'nail' in line:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.replace(line, line+'\n'+'hammer'+'\n')
        print(line)
```

after modification:

```py
import fileinput


file_name = '/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/HWDataList.txt'


for line in fileinput.FileInput([file_name], inplace=True):
    new_line = line + 'hammer' if 'nail' in line else line.rstrip()
    line = line.replace(line, new_line)
    print(line)
```

This is a general suggestion, which can meet the requirements, but the actual situation depends on the specific scene.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is not huge(`.readlines()` loads all lines in memory), you can do:

```py
file_name = '/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/HWDataList.txt'
with open(file_name, "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines.insert(lines.index("nail\n") + 1, "hammer\n")
    f.seek(0)  # Move cursor to the beginning of the file.
    f.writelines(lines)
```

If you're not sure that `"nail\n"` exists, wrap it in a try-except block.